# Python Raspberry pi mysql Link remote db

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying link a Raspberry pi to a remote database to trigger upon a change in the data. I have been looking over code samples and can get into the database when i run in the command line, 
`mysql --port=3306 --host=###.###.###.### -u travis -p pw` 
but now I am trying to create a python script to run on boot up that will execute the link, and monitor the data. This is the code that I have been trying:

```
import MySQLdb
db = MyuSQL.connect(port="3306", host="###.###.###.###", user="travis", passwd="pw", db="database"
db.close()
```

This returns an error of:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
file"test.py",line 3, in <module>
db = MyuSQL.connect(port="3306", host="###.###.###.###", user="travis", passwd="pw", db="database"
return connection (*args, **kwargs)
super(Connection, self).___int___(*args, **kwargs2)
typeError:an integer is required
```

any ideas?
Thank you for your help

Travis

Comment: What exactly is your question here?  How to "monitor the data"?  If so, please be more specific.

Comment: at this point im am trying to link to the database with a python script that is not working

Answer (score 0):

You should make port=3306 not port="3306"

Comment: I tried this but still didnt work, I reconfirmed that when I use all the same data in the command line it will link...

Comment: mysql --port=3306 --host=###.###.###.### -u travis -p pw     From here I can see the database and edit it. Im not sure what the difference is?